# DataFrame: To find a specified row and assign a numeric value to another column in the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.6, pandas-loc

When the conditional expression, c1 = 2017-04-01 holds, we want to substitute the number 300.0 for c3.

As a result, 300.0 is substituted for r3 and c3.
However, the conditional expression is not r3
columns: c1 = 2017-04-01 is r3 to be organized, so it becomes the line.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(
  [["2017-02-01",10.,100.],
  ["2017-03-01",20.,'Nan'],
  ["2017-04-01",30.,'Nan'],
  ["2017-05-01",40.,'Nan']],
  index=['r1','r2','r3','r4'],
  columns=['c1','c2','c3']
  )
df

###########################
     c1           c2    c3
r1  2017-02-01  10.0    100
r2  2017-03-01  20.0    Nan
r3  2017-04-01  30.0    Nan
r4  2017-05-01  40.0    Nan
```

What should I do?

Comment: `df.loc[df['c1'] == '2017-04-01', 'c3'] = 300`

Comment: @RafaelC
That's exactly the answer I was looking for.
 thank you very much.
 I am very grateful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use

```
df.loc[(df['c1'] == '2017-04-01'), ['column_you_need_to_change']] = 1.
```

The above line finds all rows whose c1 column has '2017-04-01' as a value and changes the desired column(s)' values to a number, in the above case 1.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for posting. The commentary was easy to understand and it was saved.